# How can I take the difference of two overlapping byte streams in Python?

Tags: python, audio, stream, byte, botocore

I have an audio stream coming in from an API call which generated text-to-speech; I am currently generating overlapping chunks of consecutive texts and want to only write the difference between a stream chunk and the one preceding it (excluding the overlap), how can I do that when what I'm dealing with are byte streams and not actual audio/text streams?

Here's an example:

let's say at iteration 0, I make an API call with the text `I am feeling good` and that returns an audio stream which is written to a file

now at iteration 1, I make another API call with the text `feeling good because I` and that returns an audio stream too, but what I want to do is skip the overlapping `feeling good` and append the remaining part `because I` from the audio stream to the file. Any suggestions on how to do this when I'm working with byte streams instead of text?

here's what I have so far, which is storing the previous stream and the current one, but how can I take the difference here?

```
for i in sentences:
   curr_audio_stream = API_call(i) #Returns a botocore.response.StreamingBody object
   with open("file.mp3", "ab") as file:
      file.write(curr_audio_stream.read())
   prev_audio_stream = curr_audio_stream
```

Here's an example bunch of texts overlapping:

```
1. Oh, that sounds like
2. a fun game!  Let's do it! So
3. Let's do it! So do you want to
4. do you want to start by giving me
5. start by giving me a clue about the
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be far simpler to process the overlapping sentences strings and prevent overlap, instead of removing the overlap from the audio? I can't imagine the text to speech API returns identical bytes when fed the same strings...

Comment: The previous comment does bring up a good point. This brings to mind whether you can use a library that might actually help you do all that work for you? There most definitely is something out there that helps read mp3 files in Python?

Comment: So the constraint here is that I need the overlap when the audio is generated from the API, but don’t need it for writing to the file.

Comment: So you want to know if the first X bytes of the new sample are identical to the final X bytes of the previous sample?  Then it seems the only difficulty is choosing the value of X.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, if it helps, the text chunks coming in are of constant length. But how does slicing work with bytes? I can do this easily with text but with I’ve never worked with bytes

Comment: Slicing works exactly the same with bytes as it does with text.  So you should be able to just use `if prev_audio_stream[X:] == cur_audio_stream[:X+1]` (assuming that they are raw streams and don't have any header/footer bytes.)

Comment: Can you do something like `output = curr_audio_stream[len(prev_audio_stream):]`?

Comment: @skidjoe That assumes the current stream contains the _entire_ previous stream, which I don't think is the case.  They only overlap by a little bit at each end.